# codeigniter html email missing images

Tags: php, codeigniter, html-email

I am using phpMailer library in codeigniter to send html emails,
In this library, i need to load contents and then pass it to some function,

I only find this below method to load view from views in library as a string to assign email 'body' like,

```
function send_mail($data=array()) {
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    $this->CI =& get_instance();
    $body = $this->CI->load->view('partials/email_template', $data, true);
    //setting third parameter to true will convert view to string, 
}
```

Email is being send correctly, but when without images, its only because string cannot contains images if iam not wrong, is there any alternative way to achieve this.

**EDIT**

Independently to the framework, 
i am loading contents as,

```
$body = file_get_contents('email_template.html');
```

But, this does not work in framework like,

```
$body = file_get_contents($this->CI->load->view('partials/email_template', $data));
//even setting the third parameter 'true'
```

and returns me "Message body empty" error..

Many thanks in advance..

Comment: can you show your email content? Maybe path issues

Comment: no path issue, as i mentioned below, iam updating my question in a while..

Comment: you mean file_get_contents is not getting content for CI view file?

Comment: yes, like that, but from my libraries folder.

Comment: @faanahmed What do you mean by `missing images`? Do the images have absolute paths in their `src` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Because the email is online, it can't just use relative urls and needs to be absolute e.g (`http://website.co.uk/partials/email_template/image.png`).

This is because the client getting the e-mail obviously wont have those files local on their computer (or very doubtful).

Comment: everything is fine, i i test this function independently to the framework, all images are loading fine in my email inbox.

Answer (score 0):

```
$body = $this->CI->load->view('partials/email_template', $data,true);
```

This will assign the view file cotent to you variable `$body`

Comment: as i mentioned in my question before edit, that if i set third parameter to true, and code exactly you answered, it send email without images, just because, setting third parameter to 'TRUE' convert contents to string, and miss images..

Comment: did you set content type in email header?

Comment: yeah, how it can send the rest html?

Comment: did you try my solution now?

Comment: please see my question code first, $body = $this->CI->load->view('partials/email_template', $data, true);
i was using the same,

Comment: can you post the content you are receiving in mail? Or you have to check with PHP email code instead of using PHPMailer. I think problem in PHPMailer.